# How to assign a class to a node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

SO I would like to create a class for this variable.

```
            elements.newClass = 'test';




 document.createElement('div');
 div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
 var count  =  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
    for( i = 0; i <= count.length; i++){
        var elements = '<div>'+ i +'<div>';
            elements.newClass = 'test';
            document.body.append(elements);
    }
```

Comment: Hint: your current code tries to add a `.newClass` property to a string value (`elements` is just a string, not a DOM element).

Comment: Ok thank you, how would I be able to fix my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Given a reference to a DOM element, you assign a class by either setting the [`.className` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) or by calling the [`.classList.add()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

In your code you don't have a reference to a DOM element, your `elements` variable is just a string. You can instead use [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create your div, then set its content and class, as follows:

```js
var classes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
   var div = document.createElement('div'); // create the DOM element
   div.innerText = i;                       // then set whichever of its
   div.className = classes[i];              // properties you need to set
   document.body.append(div);               // then append it to the body
}
```

```css
.a { color: blue; }
.b { color: red; }
.c { color: green; }
.d { color: pink; }
```

<s>I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `count` array:</s> your current loop only uses the loop counter values, it doesn't use the values from the array. If you want the values from the array to be displayed then change the line that sets the content to be this:

```
div.innerText = count[i];
```

**Update:** You said in a comment you wanted to have an array of class names and assign one to each new element. I've updated the code above to do that. Note that the loop condition should use `<` rather than `<=`, and you should declare `i` with `var`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, very useful !!

Comment: My gold wast create a an array of classes

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a group of elements where each one has the next class from the array?

Comment: You should avoid using `innerText` in a loop, this property is CSS aware and will thus trigger a reflow when set/gotten. You should prefer `textContent`.

Comment: @Kaiido - Good to know, but how much of a reflow will there be on an element that hasn't been added to the DOM yet?

Comment: @nnnnnn good point ;-) I missed that. I have to admit I don't really know how this MonSter property does react in such a case. I guess it's ok, but still better to avoid it IMM.